# C#'s implementation of the TripleDES algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, encryption

I am implementing an application that needs to use TripleDES encryption with keys of size 112 bits (14 bytes), is that possible in C#, since the documentation states that the algorithm permits keys only in the range 128-192 bits.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you left pad the 112 bit key with zero bytes to make it 128.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 128-bit key size is the 112-bit version. With each 64-bit DES key, 8 bits are parity.

[Edit: Following paragraph is from an incorrect reading of the above question, which is two-key TripleDES rather than DoubleDES. Thanks to GregS for pointing this out.]

Also note that double DES is not stronger than normal DES due to a [meet in the middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack) attack. Only use double DES for backwards compatibility. Consider AES for most purposes (or the older RC4 for SSL until TLS 1.1. or better BEAST attack protection is more prevalent).

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) contradicts your second paragraph: "This option is stronger than simply DES encrypting twice, e.g. with K1 and K2, because it protects against meet-in-the-middle attacks." Any idea why?

Comment: @JonSkeet It does two rounds of encryption so yes brute forcing it takes longer. However, if you have access to both the ciphertext and plaintext, the man in the middle attack is possible and almost halves the protection. That is why TripleDES is in common use rather than DoubleDES.

Comment: @GregS, yes, you are correct. I misread the original question. I will fix my answer.

Comment: So i have received the 14 bytes to use as the DES key over the network, how to make them work with your explanation, should i pad the key, should i set the parity bits my self, or what to do ?

Comment: @Sniffer I have never actually tried this but, according to the DES standard (http://www.itl.nist.gov/fipspubs/fip46-2.htm), you'll need to put seven bits at a time into the upper 7 bits of each byte of the key and set the least significant of the bit to 1 or 0 to as odd parity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit).

Comment: @akton Thanks for help, i had some misconceptions cleared, i thought TripleDES used triple DES key sizes, and now i know that the algorithm just runs three times with two different keys of the same size (hence two 56 bits keys = 112 bits).

Comment: @Sniffer TripleDES can run in two key or three key modes so you were not wrong before. As with most things cryptographic, it's just more complex than you (,me and everyone else) first thought.